# Where can I find desktop Ubuntu releases on a vmdk?

Tags: ubuntu, vdi, vmdk

Any official or de-facto websites that supply this ?

Details: I specifically need Ubuntu 10.04 LTS desktop version,
in general; ubuntu desktop LTS versions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not found any official ubuntu website distributing vmdk's.

According to
http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/

very few suppliers of ubuntu desktop on vmdk exist (3 to be exact).

This seems to be focused on vm creation and distribution, and for now I consider this the de-facto website to go to for ubuntu desktop vmdk's:
http://vmplanet.net/

These guys seem to have vm creation and distribution as a side-project to their main line of business:
http://www.quotrader.com/
http://www.bitconstructor.com/

Comment: Unfortunately for me, I cannot use vmplanet.net's vmdks, since they are using a vmdk split disk, which has flaky support in virtualbox. But if you're a vmware only shop, no problem.

Answer (score 4):

You can find many VMs on [VMware's site](http://www.vmware.com/appliances/directory/1147063).

Open the site and go to "Virtual Appliances"; Ubuntu LTS 11.4 is one of the many images there.

> The newest Ubuntu 11.04 VMware appliance starts out of the box with a
>   desktop looking like Gnome 2.x, but can be transformed to start the
>   Unity desktop from Ubuntu. Contrary to the basic Ubuntu 11.04 image
>   this one has the latest VMware Tools installed.

Answer (score 0):

You can just install it yourself with the ISO image, but yes, there are quite a few sites that offer VMWare images for different OSs.

[One](http://www.thoughtpolice.co.uk/vmware/)
[Two](http://www.ubuntugeek.com/download-ubuntu-10-04-desktop-vmware-image.html)
[Three](http://www.trendsigma.net/vmware/ubuntu1104.html)